# Are .setContentTitle and .setCustomContentView mutually exclusive?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

Trying to create android notifications with a custom body provided by an XML file.
When I try to set the title of these notifications, it does not appear.

Oddly, the subtext continues to show just fine.

---

Showing a standard notification (no `CustomContentView`), and

```
        builder.setContentTitle("foo");
        builder.setSubText("bar");
        // builder.setCustomContentView(customNotificationView);
```

[image: notification shows title]

Both the title and subtext show.

---

If I set it to use a custom view, the title disappears. (and instead shows app name)

```
        builder.setContentTitle("foo");
        builder.setSubText("bar");
        builder.setCustomContentView(customNotificationView);
```

[image: notification doesn't show title]

---

**Am I missing something**? Does Android just not use `ContentTitle` when you have any kind of CustomView?

I assume what's happening is that the 'content' title is getting removed because we're replacing the 'content' with a new view.

**Is there any way to give a notification with custom content  a "native" title?** (instead of adding text inside the RemoteView that we treat as the title).

---

misc notes

- using AndroidX versions (`import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;`)
- The title is removed whether or not I add a decorated style (`.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());`
- - The title is removed whether or not I set the custom view via `.setContent` or `.setCustomContentView`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right! `setContentTitle` is part of [basic notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification). `builder.setCustomContentView(customNotificationView)` is [custom notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) with custom layout and custom data which you can pass inside. Of course you can do more with custom notifications but I think the freshest version of Android kills all magic of customization. For example if you have `targetSdkVersion 31+` then you cannot change background of notification on Android 12+ devices :(